# I started a job a month ago and this position is not what I had expected.

Tags: professionalism, work-environment, unprofessional-behavior, work-time

I am unvalued and not appreciated at all and twice I have been belittled.  I am a subcontractor and the personnel that I work with do not engage with me and the work is not challenging to me at all. I want to quit but, not give these people the satisfaction. I love the company I work for but, the position is not for me. I literally took a huge step down in work and I know I can use my skills in  a position that can challenge me. I am really bored and hate going to work everyday! How do I tell my boss that this job is not for me but, I would like to try for a different position within the company that uses my skills and expertise to their fullest?

Comment: Lou -- out of curiosity, why did you take a job that was beneath you in the first place? Why didn't you just apply for the job that fits your skills? Some companies are good about switching teams, but if the switch involves two jobs that have a major difference in pay and responsibility, it's less likely to get the switch. Also, if your team is small and only a few people have your same position you'll probably have to wait until they hire another person to fill your current position, train them and then transfer you.

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to reality.

But to be serious, this is how things work.

Not trying to offend but this post comes across as a bit whiny.

The way to approach this situation is to excel in what you are assigned.  Keep doing that for a while, show people that you are *more* than capable of doing the work.

If you ever get a sit down with your boss, you will be in a good position to ask for a more difficult position.

Answer (score 2):

> I am unvalued and not appreciated at all and twice I have been
>   belittled. I am a subcontractor and the personnel that I work with do
>   not engage with me and the work is not challenging to me at all.

Did you know the work wouldn't be challenging when you started? You mentioned you took a step down, why did you do this?

> I love the company I work for

How can you love a company you have worked 1 month for and hate going to work every day?

> I am really bored and hate going to work everyday! How do I tell my
>   boss that this job is not for me but I would like to try for a
>   different position within the company that uses my skills and
>   expertise to their fullest?

Does this different position exist? Are they recruiting for this position?

This whole thing to me sounds like you have taken a step down and have underestimated how boring taking a step down is. If your employer has a role more to your level, apply for it. Otherwise, it's unlikely they will create a role for you (after all, you have only been there a month). So you may need to move on to a different company

Answer (score 1):

As Charles Addis points out. **Do not take jobs below you.** The answer of NZKshatriya also applies, but does not handle the mistake you made. **You are the position.** If you take a junior role, you are the newbie the juniors are. Even if you could be a senior or manager, you should apply to be such, not assume that if they hire a junior they immediately think that you are worth to be a senior even if you are.

I would talk to the boss about this after you have something to prove your skill, or look for a job that is not below you.

An example: You are an architect, but take a job of shoveling gravel. Then you complain that you could actually design houses, but took the job because you like the company. You have clearly made a mistake. The case of OP is probably not as striking, but fundamentally it is the same.

Answer (score 0):

**Start looking for a new job.**

The reality is - some jobs and some companies are just bad.

Trying to make the job better, is most probably going to be fruitless.

The thing is - it might take you longer than you anticipate to find a new job - which is why you need to start looking now.

Don't worry about appearing disloyal to potential future employers - if they ask just say 'It's apparent that it's not the kind of job I'm looking for - I'm bored in my position'. They'll appreciate that that does happen.

Comment: I would not advise just to start looking for a new job.  Not all prospective employers are looking for people who use "I am bored in my position."  That type of mentality on the part of the employee can come across as a red flag to the employer.  It can give the employer the impression that the employee may leave after being hired if said employee is not satisfied with the work.  And no one wants to hire someone, only to have to rehire for the same position a short time later.

Comment: @NZKshatriya That's why you go for "the job wasn't a good fit for me".